# Lookback Query utilizing Change Data Capture in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, change-data-capture

I'm using SQL Server 2014 to maintain a small database and while looking for a way to keep a History of my Data I came upon the Change Data Capture Mechanism.

My question now is if there is an easy way to create a lookback query using Change Data Capture, so I could for example query against the database state from 3 Days Ago.

I could do all that with temporary tables but I kind of doubt I'm the first one thinking about this and maybe there's even a built in capability i missed.

Any other way to manage lookback queries is also appreciated :)

Comment: Further research revealed that SQL Server 2016 has a Feature called Temporal Tables, this might be exactly what i need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx